# Slight tweak to jQuery Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have a basic jQuery Accordion working in my demo. I click 'About Us' and it reveals 'Team' link below it. Yay!

Now, is it possible to get this Accordion to work *without* having to have the 'item' class in the hyperlink?

So instead of `<a href="/about-us/" class="item">About Us</a>` it would just be `<a href="/about-us/">About Us</a>`? The reason I ask is the code currently being generated from WordPress doesn't include the 'item' class and therefore breaks my accordion.

Here is my **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/h32dj/

And my JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('#accordion a.item').click(function (e) {
    //remove all the "Over" class, so that the arrow reset to default
    $('#accordion a.item').not(this).each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('rel')!='') {
    $(this).removeClass($(this).attr('rel') + 'Over');
    }
    $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp("slow");
    });

    //showhide the selected submenu
    $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle("slow");

    //addremove Over class, so that the arrow pointing downup
    $(this).toggleClass($(this).attr('rel') + 'Over');
    e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Many thanks for any pointers here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's analyze how the `item` class is used in this script. As far as I can see it is needed to somehow distinguish between first level anchors (accordion panes) and second level anchors (content). If you need to remove this class, then you need some other way for that. For example you can rely on the markup and the tags hierarchy. Specifically instead of selector by class:

```
'#accordion a.item'
```

use selector by hierarchy:

```
'#accordion > li > a'
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/URYzK/2/).

Comment: Demo works beautifully!! Thank you!!! Now I'm just going to try and integrate into my solution. Back in 2 mins :)

Comment: That worked beautifully - many, many thanks for your detailed reply and the solution too. Have a great day!!!

Comment: Hi @Andrei. Only slight issue I have now noticed is that when I click 'News' it doesn't navigate anywhere. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk, sure there is. Notice this `e.preventDefault();` in the very end of click handler. It prevents the default behavior of the element - for anchor it means opening of new link. So what you can do is perform this prevention optionally, depending on the presence of child elements: if there are children, prevent default behavior and open pane, otherwise do not prevent default behavior and navigate to link.

Comment: Aaah perfect. Could you possibly update the fiddle showing where `e.preventDefault();` should go? I'm just a little unsure where to put it in the script :)

Answer (score 0):

Without the item class, it would work along the lines of:

```
    jQuery(function($) {

    $('#accordion > li > a').click(function (e) {
    //remove all the "Over" class, so that the arrow reset to default
        $('#accordion a').not(this).each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('rel')!='') {
                $(this).removeClass($(this).attr('rel') + 'Over');
            }
        $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp("slow");
    });

    //showhide the selected submenu
    $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle("slow");

    //addremove Over class, so that the arrow pointing downup
    $(this).toggleClass($(this).attr('rel') + 'Over');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

[**Link to jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/UAGKM/)

Comment: Hi Marty. That's perfect. Andrei posted a minute or so just before you with a similar answer. Many thanks for putting this answer together for me, it helps me understand it a little more :)